There is an internal server error when sending an email

Internal server error occurs when a verification e mail sent.

here verification ,
// Send Verification Email
const sendVerificationEmail = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

  if (!user) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }

  if (user.isVerified) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User already verified");
  }

  // Delete Token if it exists in DB
  let token = await Token.findOne({ userId: user._id });
  if (token) {
    await token.deleteOne();
  }

  //   Create Verification Token and Save
  const verificationToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex") + user._id;
  console.log(verificationToken);

  // Hash token and save
  const hashedToken = hashToken(verificationToken);
  await new Token({
    userId: user._id,
    vToken: hashedToken,
    createdAt: Date.now(),
    expiresAt: Date.now() + 60 * (60 * 1000), // 60mins
  }).save();

  // Construct Verification URL
  const verificationUrl = `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/verify/${verificationToken}`;
  //Send  Verification email

  const subject = "Verify Your Account - PrimeLodge";
  const send_to = user.email;
  const sent_from = process.env.EMAIL_USER;
  const reply_to = "noreply@primelodge.com";
  const template = "verifyEmail";
  const name = user.name;
  const link = verificationUrl;

  try {
    await sendEmail(
      subject,
      send_to,
      sent_from,
      reply_to,
      template,
      name,
      link
    );
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Email Sent" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // Log the error
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Email not sent, please try again" });
  }


});

I want to send an verification email to new user, when I clicked   [enter  can anyone help to fix this . Thank you

Does the user exists ? the code first checks if the user exists and if not throws the error .....

yes user already exist

Your authMiddleware.js is throwing an error. Is that the code you shared? Doesn't look like it.
